# How to decrease a size of a specific bucket in unordered_set by one?

Tags: c++, unordered-set

I am using `std::unordered_set` to count how many different numbers do I have in my array.
What I am trying to do is to decrease a size of a specific bucket by one when one of the occurrences of a number is being deleted from my array.

I tried using `erase()`, but that removes the whole bucket. Is there any possibility to do it somehow?

It should work like this:

```
std::unordered_set<int> P;
P.insert(0);
P.insert(0);

printf("%d", P.count(0)); //this prints 2

//P.decrease(0) <-- I'm looking for something like this
printf("%d", P.count(0)); //this should print 1
```

Comment: Can you say more about what the problem is? You want to just count the occurrences of some item?

Comment: @Carlos I've got big N * N array in which I check every K * K area, counting how many unique numbers are inside this K * K area. To do it I use std::unordered_set. As the K might be very big, I do not want to delete the number of unique numbers each time I move my K * K area by one, so I want to count off the elements from row on the left, and add elements from the row on the right.

Comment: I think I know what you mean. It might make sense to make an example. To solve it you need to do something like a prefix sum for each area where the top left corner is the root.

But hard to know what you mean with no example.

Comment: @Carlos I added example to the question.

Comment: you need a better example. Where is the NxN matrix?

Comment: @Carlos This is just the detail, my problem is how to decrease the number of this specific bucket by one.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a count with set. Everything is either in the set, or not in the set. Perhaps you want to use a map? I just wrote some sample code to demonstrate the difference.

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set
    std::unordered_set<int> s;

    std::cout << "Things are either in the set, or not in the set. There is no count." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "insert 0" << std::endl;
    s.insert(0);
    std::cout << "insert 0" << std::endl;
    s.insert(0);

    std::cout << "have we seen a 0, yes or no? " << s.count(0) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "erase 0" << std::endl;
    s.erase(0);
    std::cout << "have we seen a 0, yes or no? " << s.count(0) << std::endl;

    // http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map
    std::unordered_map<int, int> m;
    std::cout << "Every key in the map has a value. We can use that to represent count." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "add 1 to the count for value 0" << std::endl;
    m[0] += 1;
    std::cout << "add 1 to the count for value 0" << std::endl;
    m[0] += 1;

    std::cout << "How many zeroes are in the bucket? " << m[0] << std::endl;

    std::cout << "subtract 1 from the count for key==0" << std::endl;
    m[0] -= 1;
    std::cout << "How many zeroes are in the bucket? " << m[0] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Or maybe `std::unordered_multiset`. Though if the counts are going to be largeish, `map` could still be the better answer.